# Plain text field validation for protection against XSS attack

Tags: java, security, xss

We have a few plain textfields in our application that we are trying to protect against XSS. For example, comment field for users to comment on a post which is plain field. User is not expected to have the ability to change formatting but they should be able to write anything in plain text, including different languages, special characters such as @,&,',*, etc.
We are also OK with not allowing "<" and ">".

So with that in mind, would it suffice if I check for input String in the server side (Java) and fail the validation should the user use ">" or "<"? would that expose any security concern or limitation?

```
public boolean isValid(String value) {
  if (value == null) {
    return true;
  }
  // Setting an arbitrary large number (should be enough for any article/text)
  if (value.length() > 50000) {
    return false;
  }

  return !value.contains(">") && !value.contains("<");
}
```

Comment: Format output correctly instead of trying to play input Whack-a-Mole. (In Thymeleaf, for example, `th:text` automatically HTML-escapes appropriately.)

Comment: @chrylis, I do understand and agree that's the more correct approach. However at this phase, we are trying to have a quick fix that would validate (rather than sanitize) the input. With that in mind, do you believe there is an issue with the above solution?

Answer (score 0):

Input validation is not a sufficient protection against XSS in general. The question lacks enough detail to tell whether it's exploitable in this specific case, but either way, relying on input validation only is not a good idea.

If you are planning to implement this as a generic measure against XSS for multiple views across an application, it will almost certainly fail.

Consider input like `" onclick="alert(1)" x="`, or `javascript:alert(1)` for href and so on. And we haven't even mentioned the ultimate case of view templates with `<script> var myvar = {{variable}}; </script>` and similar. It's an endless can of worms.

The only way to actually prevent XSS is to implement proper output encoding *according to the context* output gets written to (html, attribute, javascript, etc.) Even then, you still have to be careful about `javascript:` and stuff written directly into a Javascript context.